# firefox user profile missing

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

On firing up firefox, I get an error as

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible
```

I had moved my `/home` to a different partition and didn't backup my `~/.mozilla`. So how can I create a new fresh firefox profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run firefox with the -P option (-p or -ProfileManager would also work) to start it with the profile manager. Use that to create a new profile and make it the default. On a Mac you'd run

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P

for instance.